# Holography vs edge modes in Chern-Simons theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-hall-effect, holographic-principle, chern-simons-theory

There are two facts I have heard about Chern-Simons theories

1. They are dual to a WZW theory on the boundary (e.g. [Relation between CS/WZW and AdS/CFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293218/59281)).
2. They require a chiral theory on the boundary due to the requirements of gauge invariance. (e.g. [Anomaly inflow mechanism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541325/59281))

The latter notion of the boundary theory has relevance to the edge modes in the quantum hall effect.

How are these two ideas relating 2+1d Chern-Simons to a 1+1d theory compatible? Are they the same? Is the theory in point 1 also chiral (corresponding to only including the holomorphic sector)? Is the theory in point 2 coupled to the gauge field (which I don't believe is the case for point 1)?

Comment: The part I can answer is that the WZW model is indeed chiral.